# Need to truncate output of template in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and want to truncate output(to 150 char, if beyond that) created by a template(below).

```
<!-- output the field description   -->
<xsl:template name="Desc">
    <xsl:value-of select="@description"/>
    <!-- append the description with the options for choiceFields   -->
    <xsl:if test="name() = 'choiceField'">
        <xsl:for-each select="./child::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@data,'=',@tag)"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to truncate the whole output?

Comment: After concatenating choicefields, i have to check the length and truncate.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML, and the output you expect from it (maybe truncated to 50 characters, to keep things shorter). Thank you.

Comment: Someone commented below code { <xsl:variable name="desc">
  <xsl:call-template name="Desc"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring($desc, 1, 150)"/>} and then removed his response. It helped and resolved my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: the original answer was by [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228), but he deleted his answer (no reason given) and the OP [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201724/need-to-truncate-output-of-template-in-xslt/32216241#comment52292943_32201724) that the answer was actually correct. Hence I'll repeat it here for completeness, but if Martin undeletes his answer, I will remove this duplicate.

---

As it is a named template the template itself will not output anything, you need to call it. If you don't want its complete output then capture the result in a variable and use only 150 characters of that variable e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="desc">
  <xsl:call-template name="Desc"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($desc, 1, 150)"/>
```